# How do I make a randomized autoresponse with a user mention in it

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

I'd like to make a command that goes as follows:

> o!hug [@user1]
>
> [@user1] is being hugged by [@user2]! [one of three gifs]

Can anybody help me? I know how to make an autoresponse with a ping but I don't know how to randomize the response/gif.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var gif=["gif","Gif","giF"];
var ran=Math.floor(Math.random()*gif.length)
if(ran=0){
    //code
}
```